# MyriadPro metric file not found

Tags: fonts, installing

I just made a fresh install of OS X El Capitan and subsequently installed a fresh Tex distribution as well. So I installed the TexLive distribution from MacTex and updated everything using Tex Live Utility. Then, I wanted to use [these scripts](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) to install MinionPro and MyriadPro. MinionPro works like a charm if I follow the instructions given. However, with MyriadPro everything seems to work fine but if I compile the following Latex file

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{MyriadPro}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My very first chapter}

Some words...

\end{document}
```

I won't see the chapter title, only the normal content, though in the correct font. The error messages I get read

```
./main.tex:12: Font OT1/MyriadPro-OsF/bx/n/20.74=MyriadPro-Bold- at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.12 \chapter{My very first chapter}

./main.tex:12: Font \OT1/MyriadPro-OsF/b/n/20.74=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

so I guess it has something to do with the font size for chapters being big and that the metrics for those have been messed up during installation or whatever. How can I fix this?